# Passing white space arguments to script (2 strings embedded)

Tags: shell

I am having script `X.sh` that calls script `y.sh`. Each of those has arguments, so the command looks something like this:

```
./X.sh -Xarg1 value -Yarg "-yarg1 -yarg2"
```

Meaning:
`-Xarg1 value` --> This is an argument for script X.sh
`-Yarg "-yarg1 -yarg2"` --> -yarg1 -yarg2 are passed as arguments to script Y.sh

Now, the problem is:
`Y.sh` also calls another script: `Z.sh`
Is there a way to pass a string including whitespaces to Z.sh?

```
./X.sh -Xarg1 value -Yarg "-yarg1 -yarg2 -Zarg 'arguments here'"
```

The code above doesn't work.

Comment: Your approach is correct. However you don't show how `X.sh` passes on the argument string found for `-Yarg` to `Z.sh`, so maybe the problem lies there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with how I call the command from within the script.. Simply executing the command in the shell script doesnt work because of how it handles arguments. Storing it in a variable $cmd and then calling eval($cmd) works